# Problems finding string Requests using Chrome Dev Tools

Tags: debugging, request, google-chrome-devtools, reverse-engineering

Im trying to reproduce Get request to this page - [URL](https://www.grubhub.com/restaurant/buffalo-wild-wings-3663-las-vegas-blvd-ste-600-las-vegas/351947)
I have found the API link that provides all the data. The only problem is the `Authorization Bearer` linked to every request. 
I use search inside Chrome Dev Tools expecting to find `Request` that initializes this `Bearer` but failing to do so. All I see - `Requests` that  already use this `Bearer` in their headers, but do not see any that would return `Bearer` in the Body.
[image]

So where does it come from and what do I miss?

P.S. I assume the debug logic should be to: Go through all requests in network tab and look for the first mention of Bearer in Headers. Then Look through all requests that come before this one.

Answer (score 0):

The Authorization Bearer is probably stored in a cookie, try deleting the cookies for this domain and then make the request again, you might see it then